Simple animation hangs on first page launch
I have a simple CSS ticker animation :
<link rel="preload" href="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" as="image" type="image/svg" fetchpriority="high">

    <div class="table_container_container">
      <div class="table_container">
        <div class="table_content_1">
          <img src="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" alt="open for comissions">
          <img src="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" alt="open for comissions">
        </div>
        <div class="table_content_2">
          <img src="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" alt="open for comissions">
          <img src="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" alt="open for comissions">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

.table_content_1,
.table_content_2 {
  animation: ticker 5s infinite linear forwards;
}

@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-81%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(-31%, 0);
  }
}

Sometimes, when starting the page, the animation “stucks”, i.e. moves very slowly. But when you inspect the code, you can see that the containers and images in them moves at the right speed. I pre-load all the necessary images :
<link rel="preload" href="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" as="image" type="image/svg" fetchpriority="high">

Also, I've tried using :
will-change: transform;

@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    transform: translate3d(-81%, 0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate3d(-31%, 0, 0);
  }
}

But it didn't help. I can't find any logic for this error, as other similar animations on the site work without any problem.
I tried creating a simple CSS animation of the ticker. it worked, but when reloading the page, sometimes the animation lags

How exactly do you want the animation to work?

I believe that preload just gives the image loading a high priority, but it doesn't guarantee that the image will be fully loaded before the page starts being visible. Have you tried definitely waiting until the image(s) have all loaded before starting the ticker?

I think it might help if you could create a runnable snippet which definitely shows the problem - ie with image(s) that are large enough to create the problem (if that's what the problem is).

I think you're doing just fine, only need to adjust the translation values.
Please consider following changes in your code.
Basically I have changed the transition values from negative to positive.
The first one, the starting point is of negative and the second one ending point of positive.
<link rel="preload" href="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" as="image" type="image/svg" fetchpriority="high">

<div class="table_container_container">
   <div class="table_container">
      <div class="table_content_1">
         <img src="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" alt="open for comissions">
         <img src="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" alt="open for comissions">
      </div>
      <div class="table_content_2">
         <img src="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" alt="open for comissions">
         <img src="../media/main/comissions_table_borderless_comp.svg" alt="open for comissions">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>



.table_content_1,
.table_content_2 {
  animation: ticker 10s infinite linear forwards;
}

@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
  }
}

Hope, this helps.

Could you explain why this solves the problem of the animation running slowly on first loading?

The problem with the actual code is the it start with higher negative value and ends in smaller negative value, changing the end point to positive one eases out the animation.
Open to correct myself, please let me know what I am missing here.
Thank you.

I think the problem being stated in the question is to do with running slowly on first page load - ie the problem does not occur all the time, so I don't see how altering the % values tackles that.

Yes, you're right.  What I considered that the animation is working fine as it should it's only the values are not defined properly hence it could be the reason it is appearing like not working properly.
